# Adding percent column to data frame

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a pandas df like the following:

```
User    Purchase_Count    Location_Count
1       2                 3
2       10                5
3       5                 1
4       20                4
5       2                 3
6       2                 3
7       10                5
```

How would I add a column that calculates the % of the coordinate pair `(Purchse_Count[i], Location_Count[i])` of the total entries.
so for example I would like the df to look like:

```
User    Purchase_Count    Location_Count    %
1       2                 3                 42.85
2       10                5                 28.57
3       5                 1                 14.28
4       20                4                 14.28
5       2                 3                 42.85
6       2                 3                 42.85
7       10                5                 28.57
```

Comment: I'd recommend accepting @juanpa.arrivillaga's answer.  It's quicker and arguably more idiomatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `pandas` solution would be to use `groupby` then `transform`:

```
In [43]: df
Out[43]:
   User  Purchase_Count  Location_Count
0     1               2               3
1     2              10               5
2     3               5               1
3     4              20               4
4     5               2               3
5     6               2               3
6     7              10               5

In [44]: total = len(df)

In [45]: df['percentage'] = df.groupby(['Purchase_Count', 'Location_Count']).transform(lambda r: r.count()/total)

In [46]: df
Out[46]:
   User  Purchase_Count  Location_Count  percentage
0     1               2               3    0.428571
1     2              10               5    0.285714
2     3               5               1    0.142857
3     4              20               4    0.142857
4     5               2               3    0.428571
5     6               2               3    0.428571
6     7              10               5    0.285714
```

#### Edit to improve readability

```
In [53]: df['percentage'] = (df.groupby(['Purchase_Count', 'Location_Count'])
    ...:                     .transform(lambda r: r.count()/total))

In [54]: df
Out[54]:
   User  Purchase_Count  Location_Count  percentage
0     1               2               3    0.428571
1     2              10               5    0.285714
2     3               5               1    0.142857
3     4              20               4    0.142857
4     5               2               3    0.428571
5     6               2               3    0.428571
6     7              10               5    0.285714
```

#### Edit:

As suggested by @piRSquared, you could use:

```
df.groupby(['Purchase_Count', 'Location_Count']).transform('count') / total
```

Instead, and preliminary tests show it is significantly faster.

Comment: Since `total` is constant you should be able to get away with `df.groupby(['Purchase_Count', 'Location_Count']).transform('count') / total`  Either way +1

Answer (score 2):

use `groupby` with `size` and `join`

```
cols = ['Purchase_Count', 'Location_Count']
df.join(df.groupby(cols).size().div(len(df)).rename('%'), on=cols)

   User  Purchase_Count  Location_Count         %
0     1               2               3  0.428571
1     2              10               5  0.285714
2     3               5               1  0.142857
3     4              20               4  0.142857
4     5               2               3  0.428571
5     6               2               3  0.428571
6     7              10               5  0.285714
```

***old answer***

Using `pd.value_counts` on tuples

```
tups = df[['Purchase_Count', 'Location_Count']].apply(tuple, 1)
df.assign(**{'%': tups.map(pd.value_counts(tups, normalize=True))})

   User  Purchase_Count  Location_Count         %
0     1               2               3  0.428571
1     2              10               5  0.285714
2     3               5               1  0.142857
3     4              20               4  0.142857
4     5               2               3  0.428571
5     6               2               3  0.428571
6     7              10               5  0.285714
```

---

***timing***

[image]